# Table of expanded electronic structures of atoms

Tags: atoms, electronic-configuration, orbitals, periodic-table

Where can I find the table containing expanded electronic configurations for atoms in the periodic table, showing how outer electrons are distributed between different atomic orbitals?

I really just need to know the expanded electronic configurations of sulfur S and tungsten W.

So, for sulfur, amongst others, there are $p_x%$, $p_y$, $p_z$ atomic orbitals. And for tungsten W, amongst others, there are $d_{xy}, d_{xz}, d_{yx}, d_{x^2-y^2}, d_{z^2}$ atomic orbitals. I need to know how exactly electrons are distributed.

Does anyone have any idea where I can find the information or how I can derive it?

Comment: They are degenerated for partial-filling case..

Comment: [tungsten](https://www.webelements.com/tungsten/), [sulfur](https://www.webelements.com/sulfur/)?

Comment: The information you ask for **does not exist**, and **not** because of our limited understanding of nature.

Comment: Thanks @Rodriguez! You are right, I missed this moment...

Comment: This is one of those questions where I have to ask: Why? What for? Do you really get what you want with the information you requested?  You don't need to answer this comment, but maybe think about it for a second.